# Truffle MetaCoin example not working as expected

Tags: ethereum, truffle

So I have a `testrpc` running, and two instances of the initial project created with `truffle init`. And they both connect to the same `testrpc`.

1.
When I fill in an `amount` and no address, it will subtract the amount from my current balance. I would expect that same balance to show up at the other instance, which is using the same `account[0]` ID. But it doesn't, it shows the initial `10000` there, while i would expect the actual balance to be extracted from the `testrpc`? What am I doing/thinking wrong here?

2.
When I try to transfer `MetaCoins` from `account[0]` to `account[1]` (or rather, enter the id), then modify `app.js` in one of the instances to `account[1]`, run `truffle build` and refresh, the balance is still `0`.

3.
When I try the above two on the same instance/device, it does work?

I suspect that either I'm misunderstanding some fundamental thing here, or there's a bug somewhere.

Although the `testrpc` is receiving an `eth_sendTransaction` in the terminal, when either instance does a transaction..